# wdStart with multiple arguments

Tags: c, vxworks, watchdog

I've looked around for a solution to my problem but in vain. It seems like there isn't anything that addresses my issue. I highly appreciate your help.
I need to call temperatureControl() using a watchdog. However, temperatureControl takes up 2 arguments and wdStart can only call the fucntion with only 1 arg. Is there a work around for this?

> ```
> wdStart(watchDog, args.tPeriod , (FUNCPTR)temperatureControl, arg1, arg2);
> ```

Code:

> ```
> struct arguments{
> int tPeriod; /* Time in ticks used inside watchdog to change temperature*/
> int room;  /* Room targetted */
> int temperature; /* Desired temperature*/
> };
>
> /* Set the chosen room to the desired temperature after tperiod time*/
> void setTemperatureUsingWatchDog(struct arguments args)
> {
>     watchDog = wdCreate();
>     wdStart(watchDog, args.tPeriod , (FUNCPTR)temperatureControl, args);  
>     logMsg("Room #%d",args.room, "temperature is set to%f", roomTemperature[args.room],0,0,0);
> ```

Comment: try to add all the three arguments in to a `struct` and then pass the struct as one single argument

Comment: Not sure what exactly `watchdog` is, but if the types are flexible, you can always pass multiple objects as a struct.

Comment: Let me give it a shot. Thanks guys

Comment: I was able to apply what you suggest and now I'm getting the following error:
internal error: assertion failed: Invalid C99 IL expression kind (./../src/eparse/lower_c99.c, line 3690)
Here is My code:

Comment: I edit my question with my current code. Sorry it took me this long

Comment: [wdStart](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/wdLib.html) has `int` parameter, so passing `struct` will fail.

Comment: In which case, assert that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int)` and cast the pointer to an integer and back :P.

Comment: @slugonamission Had the same idea, but it's a bit hacky ;-)  I vaguely remember I've done this back in the day with VxWorks 4.

Comment: @meaning-matters - aye. Asserting that your pointers and ints are the same size will help, but...ew :(.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by using a structure, but please realize that the watchdog argument is a POINTER. It's ok to pass in an integer, but the moment you move to a real structure, then you must use a pointer to it.

In your code, you are attempting to pass in a structure and not the address of it. And please don't simply use the & operator in your code as is.  That would use a stack address which would then be used in the ISR context with unfortunate results.

Here is an example using a global (ok if you only have a single structure):

```
struct arguments myGlobalArg;
...
void setTemperature() {
   wd = wdCreate();
   wdStart(wd, myGlobalArg.tPeriod, (FUNCPTR)temperatureControl, &myGlobalArg);
}
```

If you have a number of different args, you could use a global array of structures, or dynamically allocate the structures.

The key is that the watchdog argument is a pointer to something that shouldn't be on the stack, but in globally accessible memory.